# Is the ABI required to call a contract with ethers.js?

Tags: contract-invocation, abi, ethers.js

From the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html#connecting-to-a-contract):

```js
// The Contract interface
let abi = [ ... ];

// Connect to the network
let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();

// The address from the above deployment example
let contractAddress = "...";

// We connect to the Contract using a Provider, so we will only
// have read-only access to the Contract
let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
```

I understand how this works, but I'm curious if you need the ABI at all? In web3.js, you don't, thanks to the ability to pass a contract method as a string:

```js
// in web3.js
contract.methods["someMethod()"]()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of v4 at least, the answer is *yes*, the contract ABI must be provided. Creating a contract with no ABI and no provider or signer:

```js
let tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress);
```

Yields this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Creating a contract with just no provider or signer:

```js
let tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, erc20Abi);
```

Yields this other error:

> Error: invalid signer or provider (arg="signerOrProvider", value=undefined, version=4.0.41)